# How to add multiple axis without multiple series on highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I face problem in make multiple axis without multiple series, below is my code:
  http://jsfiddle.net/W43Zb/351/

```
   var xAxis = [{
                    categories: {{ t|safe }},
                    labels: {rotation: -90}
                },{
                    categories: {{ secondxlabel|safe }},
                    labels: {rotation: -90},
                     opposite: true
                }
                ];
```

I get the idea from here
http://jsfiddle.net/W43Zb/ 
but there was not working

Comment: What framework are you using for making your charts? Is something not working in your second jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart is not loading in the fiddle because of an error generated in your initialization code.

However, to make a second axis appear on the chart, something needs to be attached to it - either a data series, or by virtue of being linked to another axis.

To be linked means that they need to be the same scale, which in your case, seems that it will work fine, as you seem to be using the second axis to show a second alternate set of labels.

So just add the `linkedTo` property to your second axis, like this:

```
[{
  categories: {{ t|safe }},
  labels: {rotation: -90}
},{
  linkedTo: 0,
  categories: {{ secondxlabel|safe }},
  labels: {rotation: -90},
  opposite: true
}]
```

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.linkedTo

Fiddle Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/f9n3dm0p/